# Azure .user.ini not working

Tags: php, azure, ini

As the azure website states, to configure PHP I should add a .user.ini file to the root.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#ChangeBuiltInPHP

The issue is when I do this, none of my php ini values seem to change. I'm pretty sure my ini file is correct?

```
upload_max_filesize=128M
post_max_size=128M
```

When I upload the file and restart the website, I check php_info() and the values are still set to the default.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

I created the first .user.ini file within FileZilla which for some reason azure didn't recognise. I then just created a user.ini file and renamed it to .user.ini within command prompt

```
ren user.ini .user.ini
```

and that file was recognised by azure.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here with the same problem, but my file was already correctly named `.user.ini`.

After some trial and error, I got it working by placing the `.user.ini` in `\home\site\wwwroot\public` instead, which is the folder from which my laravel app serves its files.

So, if you are not serving from `\home\site\wwwroot` (i.e. at some time changed the path mapping for `/` of your web app) this might be worth a try.

Comment: I also solved my problem same way.

Comment: Excellent. I have spent almost 2 days fixing this issue but your suggestion is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but locally.  Windows IIS, PHP 7 w/ WinCache, using .user.ini

First problem appeared to be cache related. After I moved the lines around in random order (in .user.ini), it finally worked. Second problem, changing max_input_vars = 1000 to 2000 had no effect, but when I moved that entire line to a different line (in .user.ini), then it worked.

Comment: i have linux web-app, in which dir you have added .user.ini (site ? OR wwwroot )also can you post its content

Comment: theoretically it should be in the wwwroot folder. see here: https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/use-azure-kudu-to-access-the-infrastructure-files-of-an-azure-hosted-wordpress-site/

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a PHP app in a Linux container and the `.user.ini` solution didn't work for me. What worked for me was the solution explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure

1. Add directory "ini" to the `\home\site` directory.
2. Add an App Setting to your app with the key PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR and value `\home\site\ini`
3. Create an ini file in `\home\site\ini` called `extensions.ini`.
4. Add configuration settings to the extensions.ini file using the same syntax you would use in a php.ini file.
5. Restart your app to load the changes.